# Improving DSL syntax

Tags: syntax, kotlin, dsl

To start learning design of DSLs using Kotlin language features, I have
the attempt below at a toy DSL for creating groups of members with members
having names. I am looking for pointers/hints on the following

1. How can I avoid having to separate groups by a semicolon, if no semicolon the compiler gives

> Groups.kt:31:45: error: unresolved reference: member
>     val grp = group { member { name ("Bob") } member { name ("Sandy") } }

2. Can i get to use a lambda for setting `name` instead of function call?
3. Can I avoid having to have `name` be mutable in class `MEMBER`?

My code is

```
fun group(create: GROUP.() -> Unit) = GROUP().apply(create)

class GROUP {
    private val members = mutableSetOf<MEMBER>()

    fun member(create: MEMBER.() -> Unit) {
        val member = MEMBER()
        member.create()
        members.add(member)
    }

    override fun toString() = members.toString()

}

class MEMBER() {
    var name = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }

    fun name(nameToSet: String) {
        name = nameToSet
    }
    override fun toString() = "MEMBER(" + name + ")"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val grp = group { member { name ("Bob") }; member { name ("Sandy") } }
    println(grp)
}
```

Currently the output of above code is

> [MEMBER(Bob), MEMBER(Sandy)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I avoid having to separate groups by a semicolon

By using the idiomatic format, using separate lines. After all, the whole point of a DSL is to make the code very readable by showing the hierarchical structure, and doing everything on a single line defeats the wole purpose:

```
val grp = group { 
    member { 
        name ("Bob") 
    }
    member { 
        name ("Sandy") 
    } 
}
```

> Can I get to use a lambda for setting name instead of function call?

It would be more logical and idiomatic to remove the name function and to simply assign a value to the property:

```
name = "Bob"
```

But yes, you can also replace your name function by

```
fun name(block: () -> String) {
    this.name = block()
}
```

and use

```
name {
    "Sandy"
}
```

> Can I avoid having to have name be mutable in class MEMBER?

Yes: the lambda passed to the member() function would customize an additional MemberBuilder class, that would be mutable, but would allow to create an immutable MEMBER:

```
fun group(create: GROUP.() -> Unit) = GROUP().apply(create)

class GROUP {
    private val members = mutableSetOf<MEMBER>()

    fun member(configure: MemberBuilder.() -> Unit) {
        val memberBuilder = MemberBuilder()
        memberBuilder.configure()
        members.add(memberBuilder.build())
    }

    override fun toString() = members.toString()

}

class MEMBER(val name: String) {
    override fun toString() = "MEMBER($name)"
}

class MemberBuilder {
    var name = "";

    fun build() = MEMBER(name)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val grp = group {
        member {
            name = "Bob"
        }
        member {
            name = "Sandy"
        }
    }
    println(grp)
}
```

Also, note that classes, by convention, are PascalCased, not ALL_CAPS.